# How to show the number of matches in find/replace for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

dumb question but I'm getting so frustrated with this. How do I show the total number of matches for find/replace as well as the number I'm currently on? This a standard feature for almost any software I can think of.

I've looked in windows -> preferences - general, and also searched for it in preferences and can't find it. Anyone know how to do this? My eclipse version is "Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)" if that matters.

Comment: Find/Replace doesn't know the number of matches as it only does a single search each time you press Next. The "Search" dialog searches show all the search results and a count in the Search view, that dialog can also do Replace.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this helps. It's annoying that I can't do this with clrt+f, though.

Comment: @MichaelSkarn With _Find_ (Ctrl+F) and _Replace All_ you can get the number of matches, but you have to do an _Undo_ (Ctrl+Z) to revert the _Replace All_.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you